# Android textview with bullet points

Tags: android

I have a scenario in which a large amount of static data is coming from server. Now i want to add bullet points after some number of words. for example like this

Header Text

• one two three four five six seven eight

• two three four five six seven eight

• three four five six seven eight

I saw many links on stackoverflow that suggest hard code '•' in strings.xml text or using "\u2022 Bullet" programmatically but in my scenario text come from server through web service. How it could be done.

```
txt_sample.setText(text from server through web services);
```

Comment: have you tried Html.fromHtml() ?

Comment: So the text comes from the server... Okay, why can't you edit the string?

Comment: only way is to edit text by adding "\u2022 Bullet"

Comment: grab your useful code from this library https://github.com/1gravity/Android-RTEditor

Comment: try using  BulletSpan class??

Comment: I think you should post sample text response from server, so other dev can suggest more specific solution